# Mocking an rvalue qualified method with gmock

Tags: c++, testing, c++20, googletest, googlemock

Is there a way I can mock an rvalue qualified method with gmock? Something like the following?

```
class Something {
public:
  virtual void test() &&;
};

class MockSomething : public Something {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, test, (), (&&, override));
};
```

Trying this seems to give me a bunch of weird compiler errors that complain about, what it looks like, are preprocessed tokens. I can also not figure out how to make the older numbered mocking macros (eg. `MOCK_METHOD1`, `MOCK_METHOD2`, etc) work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ref(...) - Marks the method with the reference qualification specified. Required if overriding a method that has reference qualifications. Eg ref(&) or ref(&&).`

Source: https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html

Comment: Somehow I'm still not able to get it to work :( I get the following error `static_assert failed due to requirement '(0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0) == 1' "ref(&&) cannot be recognized as a valid specification modifier`

Comment: @Curious `MOCK_METHOD(void, test, (), (ref(&&), override));` compile for me -- do you use latest version of googletest?